# Testing Rest Calls with karma and angular

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to test my angular rest calls with karma and jasmine. for starters I just want to test my `Auth` Service and do a simple login.

```
describe('Auth Service', function () {
    var httpBackend,
        service;

    beforeEach(function () {
        angular.mock.module('mean');

        inject(function ($httpBackend, Auth) {
            httpBackend = $httpBackend;
            httpBackend.expect('POST', '/auth/v1/login', { email: 'my@email.com', password : 'password' }).respond({
                response: {
                    success: true
                }
            });

            service = Auth;
        });
    });

    it('should login.', function () {
        var result;

        service.login('my@email.com', 'password').then(function (response) {
            result = response;
        });

        httpBackend.flush();
        // TODO
    });
});
```

I know that this code won't work as is, but unfortunately I don't even get as far as to check if the rest call is being executed properly. I get the following exception:

```
Error: Unexpected request: GET internationalization/locale-en.json
Expected POST /auth/login
```

`locale-en.json` is one of my internationalization files which I didn't reference anywhere in this Test (or even in the `Auth` Service).

here's the implementation of the login function in the `Auth` Service:

```
function login(email, password) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.post('/auth/v1/login', {email: email, password: password})
        .success(function (t) {
            $localStorage.token = t;
            deferred.resolve(t);
        })
        .error(function (err) {
            deferred.reject(err);
        });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Where does the seemingly random GET call to the json come from and what am I doing wrong here?

---

**edit:**  my karma.conf.js

```
module.exports = function (config) {
config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine',/* 'requirejs',*/ 'browserify'],

    plugins: [
        //'karma-requirejs',
        'karma-jasmine',
        'karma-browserify',
        'karma-chrome-launcher'
    ],

    files: [
         'public/bower_components/angular.js'
         // other bower_components
        'node_modules/requirejs/require.js',
        'node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/adapter.js',

        'public/app.js',
        'public/config/*.js',
        'public/controllers/**/*.js',
        // services, directives, filters, internationalization just like the ctrl's
        'public/tests/*.js'
    },
    exclude: [],
    preprocessors: {
        'public/tests/*.js': [ 'browserify' ]
    },
    // the rest is standard karma config
```

})
};

I commented require.js out since I always get the error

```
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch
  at /home/markus/git/dealscreening/node_modules/requirejs/require.js:140
```

which I can't seem to fix. I also added a `test-main.js` file for require.js (otherwise I couldn't run karma tests at all)

```
var tests = [];
for (var file in window.__karma__.files) {
    if (window.__karma__.files.hasOwnProperty(file)) {
        if (/Spec\.js$/.test(file)) {
            tests.push(file);
            console.log('requireJS:', file);
        }
    }
}

requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: '/base',
    paths: {},
    deps: tests,
    callback: window.__karma__.start
});
```

Probably my karma config is somehow wrong, unfortunately I don't really know how to configure it correctly since none of the tutorials I went through seem to work in my project.

**github example project:**

https://github.com/markus138/karmatest

to test it:

```
npm install
cd public
bower install
cd ..
npm test
```

---

versions:
angular 1.4.4
karma 0.13.9
jasmine 2.3.4

Comment: It would be helpful to see your full karma config file and test file, I suspect you are injecting a module in the beforeEach or somewhere  that is requiring this file and hence causing a issue.

Comment: I added my karma config. The more I look at my config, the more I'm sure that I'm doing something completely wrong, I just can't figure out what exactly

Comment: Look at your angular module .run() call and see if the request in question is being executed in there.

Comment: I dont have a call in .run(), but in .config(). Just for testing I commented it out. Now I get the same error, but with html views `Error: Unexpected request: GET views/home/home.html`

Comment: Do you have this code in a github repo I can't seem to figure out where the issue is coming from and it would be helpful if I could run it locally.

Comment: I added the github example project. if you comment the `public/config/translate.js` out you'll see that the next error comes. If I had to guess my `require-config.js` and/or `karma.conf.js` is wrong. Thank you for your effort!

Comment: You're loading the whole application module ('mean') in your test, and this module has a config block in translate.js which tells translate to load i18n JSON files, so that's what it does. You should avoid loading this translate.js file. You should also try to separate your components in modules, and only load the modules that contains the component under test and its dependencies, instead of loading the whole application module for each test.

Comment: I tried it again, different project, 2 modules and still the same error. I can't remove anything from my run/config block since I need it in my project. How can I get rid of this error and why is he trying to get locale-en.json when I tell him to get something completly else?

Answer (score 0):

You probably reference the main module in your test. So usually you have a router defined to it with different states. Maybe it tries to load the html because you defined it like that. You can propably ignore the call by responsing a 400 on the expectation. Greetings